# How to set style on openpyxl?

Tags: phpexcel, openpyxl

I would to set style for a whole sheet in openpyxl.
I have this code:

```
ws_names= wb.get_sheet_names()
for wsname in ws_names :
   ws= wb.get_sheet_by_name(wsname)
   cr= ws.get_squared_range('A1)
   for coli in xrange(1, 100) :
    #  issues, does not work
    col = ws.column_dimensions[da.gcol(coli)]
    col.font= Font(name='Arial', bold=False, size=8, italic=False, color="000000")
```

which does not work.
How can I set the style and none border for the whole sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#applying-styles): you need to apply the styles to individual cells.